# N5K-5672UP Packet Flow diagram

Tags: cisco-nx-os

I have one N5K-5672UP and a few SVIs with IPv4/IPv6 public IPs, I want to have an ACL and apply that ACL to my UPLINKs and deny internet traffic towards SVIs, my question is when i do this then ACL is working before CoPP? my mean is how does packet flow work in this switch, when the packet enters the switch it will check ACL, and if i denied that in the ACL then it will not check that in CoPP? (assume that traffic is towards the control plane and not the data plane)